# Clipping multiple NETcDF4 files

Tags: python, python-xarray, netcdf4

I am trying to crop a bunch of netCDF4 files and then combine them into one CSV file. I have tried using the code below but can't seem to get the for loop to work.

```
  import os
  import xarray as xr
  import netCDF4
  import pandas as pd
  import numpy as np
  import glob


  max_lat= -15
  min_lat= -20
  max_lon= -68
  min_lon= -71


 #for filename in glob.glob("/path/to/assignment/file*.txt"):
  for filename in glob.glob("D:\\Precip\\*.nc"):
    print(filename)
    data=xr.open_dataset(filename,decode_times=False)

 mask_lon = (data.longitude >= min_lon) & (data.longitude <= max_lon)
 mask_lat = (data.latitude >= min_lat) & (data.latitude <= max_lat)   

 cropped_data = data.where(mask_lon & mask_lat , drop=True)

 print(cropped_data['E'])

 df=data['P'].to_dataframe()
```

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! When asking about errors, please always include the [full traceback](//realpython.com/python-traceback). You can [edit] your question to include it. Thanks!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.